# Using an external camera in Androids Google Hangouts app

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, android-camera, google-hangouts

I want to be able to access an external camera such as a GoPro from the Google Hangouts App for Android.  Currently the app allows you to use either your front or rear facing camera.  I would like to be able to select a wifi or bluetooth paired adventure camera.  Is there a way to create an app that will interact with Androids camera APIs and the Hangouts app to allow this?

Comment: Android's camera APIs have nothing to do with external cameras. You would need support from the camera manufacturer for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot create an app that provides new Cameras to other applications.

The cameras available to your application are determined by the firmware on the device. If you create a custom ROM you might be able to get your own cameras to work with applications, but I am guessing that the Hangouts app will still not support it.

The Hangouts app is likely hard coded to only support front and back facing cameras, and thus would not show any additional cameras available to the user.